# The sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is increasing. What about $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Define the $k^\text{th}$ term of the sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of real numbers by $$a_k := k^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-kx^2} \, dx.$$
Then $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence because
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} &= \frac{(k+1)^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(k+1)x^2} \, dx}{k^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-kx^2} \, dx} \\[8pt]
&=\frac{(k+1)^2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k+1}}}{k^2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{(k+1)^{3/2}}{k^{3/2}} \\[6pt]
&\ge 1
\end{align}
for all $k \in \{1,2,\ldots\}$.

Is there, however, another approach to showing that $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence, an approach without actually evaluating the integrals? Because I actually want to show that another sequence $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, with
$$b_k := k^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-kx^2} f(x) \, dx,$$
is also increasing (assuming $f$ is non-negative, continuous, and goes to $0$ rapidly as $|x| \to \infty$).

Edit: Because of the counterexample in @kelenner's answer, I see now that $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is not always an increasing sequence.

Comment: Do you require that $f$ is a positive function? Without this condition, the answer is obviously ***no***.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ continuous?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is both continuous and positive.

Comment: In this case $f$ will be bounded so it will be easy to show the result

Comment: I had that $f$ goes to zero rapidly, but that doesn't always have to be the case, as $f$ can be some polynomial function and multiplying it by $e^{-kx^2}$ still makes the function integrable.

Comment: Anyway, assuming still that $f$ goes to zero, I would have $0 \le f(x) \le M$, definitely, but then I'm trying to show that $b_{k+1}/b_k \ge 1$, so I'm just afraid I'll run into conflicting inequalities ...

Comment: That's the problem indeed but the speed of convergence might tell us something and I am not familiar with that concept

Comment: The sequence $(b_k)$ is not always nonincreasing. The sequence $(a_k)$ is increasing, and this can be shown without estimating the integrals, showing that $a_k=k^{3/2}a_1$ for every $k$.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi I understand $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ must converge, but I would really like to know if $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is also increasing, i.e. if $b_{k+1}/b_k \ge 1$ as well.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi Why must $b_k$ converge? What if $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: *Typo: Please read "The sequence (bk) is not always nondecreasing."

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi If $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, then $b_k = k^2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k+1}}$.

Comment: @i707107 You are right, I apologize. In hind-sight I misread the question.

Comment: @GrancescoFrechi I see what you meant. Your comment was probably about $b_k/k^2$.

Comment: @i707107 No, I thought he had shown that $\{a_k\}$ was convergent in the first part, not increasing. That's why I brought up the argument of being bound. Altogether, a bad response on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take $f(x)=x^4\exp(-x^2)$, then by the change of variable $x\sqrt{k+1}=u$, your $b_k$ is $$b_k=\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2\sqrt{k+1}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u^4\exp(-u^2)du$$ and $b_k\to 0$ hence is not increasing.

Comment: Corrected: Tangential question, I know, but is it at least true that taking the supremums of the integrands, that is, $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} k^2 e^{-kx^2} f(x) \le \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} (k+1)^2 e^{-(k+1) x^2} f(x)$$ for any function $f$, even with your counterexample $f(x)=x^4e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: In the case of $f(x)=x^4\exp(-x²)$, one can use the derivative to study the function $k^2\exp(-kx^2)f(x)$, and I have found that the maximum on $\mathbb{R}$ is $M(k)=4\exp(-2)(\frac{k}{k+1})^2$, hence increasing. But this is a particular case. You can try with $x^4$ replaced by $x^n$.