# $\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} k^2e^{−kx^2}f(x)≤\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} (k+1)^2e^{−(k+1)x^2}f(x)$?

Tags: exponential-function, supremum-and-infimum

Assuming that $f$ is bounded, continuous, and non-negative, is it true that
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} k^2e^{−kx^2}f(x)≤\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} (k+1)^2e^{−(k+1)x^2}f(x)$$

I have a hard time proving this rigorously for a general $f(x)$ that meets the above criteria I mentioned.

I'm only able to see it intuitively, like this for $f(x)=e^{-x}$ (okay, I know, $e^{-x}$ is not bounded on $\mathbb R$, but thankfully it does not affect anything significantly here):

[image]

Is there a way to prove this rigorously, however? Not for any specific function $f(x)$, but for *any* arbitrary $f(x)$ that are bounded, continuous, and non-negative? I tried to prove it rigorously by taking the derivative and setting it equal to $0$, but with the appearance of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in the terms, it's hard to solve for the critical value of $x$. Perhaps there might be a way around this.

(This question is somewhat related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854266/the-sequence-a-k-k-1-infty-is-increasing-what-about-b-k-k-1-in).)

Comment: You may easily construct a Gaussian-shaped function $f(x)$ such that **the reverse** inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not exact in general.

In fact, as it can be written under the form:

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} e^{−kx^2}f(x)≤\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} e^{−kx^2}f(x)e^{−x^2},$$

setting $g(x):=e^{−kx^2}f(x)$, the issue is reduced to the following one: prove that:

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} g(x)≤\left(\dfrac{k+1}{k}\right)^2 \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} e^{−kx^2}g(x) \ \ \ (1)$$

for all functions $g$ which are a subset of functions $f$ ($>0$ continuous bounded functions).

But inequality (1) is not exact in general. It suffices to take $g_k(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+(x+3k)^2}$ (shifted Cauchy or Lorentzian function):

- the LHS of (1) has value 1, whereas
- the RHS is less than $1$ as can be readily observed by plotting a curve of the function with equation $y=\varphi_k(x):=g_k(x)e^{−kx^2}$ for any value of $k$.

Remark: A rigorous proof of the fact that the RHS of (1) is (whatever $k$) less than 1 would involve the computation of the roots of the derivative $\varphi_k'(x)$ i.e., i;e., the roots of the third degree polynomial
$$k x^3 + 6 k^2 x^2 + (9k^3 + k + 1)x + 3k.$$